# Selenium training in C# or Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, regression-testing

I want to go for a Selenium training course but was bit confused whether should I go for Java or C#.

I have been to a training session for C# earlier so as far as the concepts are concerned I do have reasonable knowledge about programming. So anyone can suggest from Java or C#.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Vik. This looks like a really simple question, but there's a lot of factors to it. I mean, imagine if someone came to you and said "I want to write an app. Should I use C# or Java?" - that's basically the same question going on here.

Comment: @corsiKa I believe my question was misunderstood completely, I just wanted assessment based on different people's experience with C# and Java. for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205928/writing-selenium-tests-in-java-or-c-sharp  and http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Which-would-be-best-programming-961927.S.276356741

Comment: I am urging to reopen my question as it was totally misunderstood. I do not want to open any discussion but instead wanted suggestions based on different tester's experience. I wanted to know if someone has released that he/she should have chosen one over another. In my comment as well, I mentioned according to trainer Java has got more plugins available than C# and only experienced testers can confirm if it is true. If I wanted any general opinion, I could have searched on google or could go somewhere else but I came here because I knew this is the place where I will get the expert advice.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, it depends.

If you're with a C# shop, it makes more sense to work with C# so you can collaborate with the developers and share code. Similarly, if you're working with a Java shop, go with Java.

A few other considerations:

- The main tool for C# development is Visual Studio. While there is a free version, the licensing for it is quite limited.
- There are a number of free tools for Java development. Eclipse is one of the better known ones.
- Selenium plugins and extensions differ depending on language. I don't know which of the languages Selenium supports has most support: that may impact which way you choose.

Other than that, C# and Java are very similar in terms of what they do and how they do it. I doubt it will be difficult for you to switch language if you need to.

Comment: Actually I was told by the trainer that Java would be a better option  as you will have more options in terms of plugins etc, than C#, So just want to know is there any practical difference or limitations one over another. I am bit comfortable in C# but as you know it is not much difference in syntax of C# and Java, and I do not want to go for one language where after some time will release that I should have chosen another one.

Comment: Vik, Kate would be extremely accurate with her assessment here. The best option is typically to choose the language that your development team utilizes that way the company as a whole can understand and utilize the utility that is being used. This prevents hit by a bus and makes the utility something easier to utilize and maintain long term, even after you are not longer with the company. If you are looking for generic training, I would suggest Java since you would also be learning Java's syntax and have a better resume.